# output the line contained in the file by keyword using perl

Tags: linux, perl

I have a file `aa.txt`:

```
John Norman
Robert Anson
Christopher Fowler
Robert Harris
Dan Simmons
```

I want to enter keywords from the keyboard and check them in the file element by line. If true, output the entire line containing that keyword.
For example, if I enter the word "John", it will output "John Norman"
How do I write perl script? (I use perl script because this is an exercise that requires the use of perl)
Thanks you very much!

Comment: Read the input into a variable, being careful to remove newline with chomp. Open the file for reading, read through the lines, check if the line matches with your input. Print if match.

Comment: The OP said in a comment to my answer that this is his homework.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want `grep`:

```
grep John aa.txt
```

You can also do it case-insensitively:

```
grep -i John aa.txt
```

But let's say that you want multiple searches in one go. The first thing to figure out, and which your question doesn't provide, is the mechanism you desire. So, I'll have the first argument be the file and the rest be the things to find:

```
% ./some_script file_to_search.txt key1 ...
```

Then it's pretty simple.

```
#!perl

my @keys = @ARGV;
@ARGV = shift @keys;

my $pattern = join '|', map { quotemeta } @keys;
my $compiled_re = qr/$pattern/;

while( <<>> ) {
    print if /$compiled_re/;
    }
```

Beyond that, you'd have to tell us much more about what you are trying to do.

```
$ perl greppy.pl aa.txt John
John Norman
$ perl greppy.pl aa.txt John Robert
John Norman
Robert Anson
Robert Harris
```

Comment: I use perl script because this is an exercise that requires the use of this language. My course is learning the basics of each linux language like grep, awk, shell, tcl. Currently i have researched on the net about perl script but nothing matches what i asked.

Comment: Ah, so it's homework. You should have told us that.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem like a `perl` question at all.  You can just do something like:

```
$ while read name; do grep -F "$name" aa.txt; done
John
John Norman
Christopher
Christopher Fowler
```

(In the above, every odd numbered line was entered by the user)

I suppose you could do it with:

```
perl -nE 'chop; open my $f, "<", "aa.txt"; while($a = <$f>) {print $a if( $a =~ $_ )}'
```

But note that either of these solutions is unusual.  Rather than "enter keywords from the keyboard", it would be more typical to pass the search terms as arguments to `grep`, or to put them all in a file.  The search can be greatly optimized if you only read the file once, and the solutions presented here are only useful if you really want to do this interactively for each search term.  Even then, it would be more natural to just invoke `grep` for each term, or write a shell function to simplify the interface.